# Problems defining a good hide/unhide jQuery function for dynamic divs

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

A while ago I used this simple function to hide/unhide `divs`':

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#job_desc').hide();
  $('#slick-toggle').click(function() {
    $('#job_desc').toggle(400);
    return false;
  });
});
```

As you can see I'm just hiding the `div` with the id `job_desc` when the document is ready, also creating a function that toggles the state of the `div` when the user clicks on the link with the id `slick-toggle`.

Well the times change, now I'm generating the `div`'s using a php loop like:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
echo '<div id="job_desc['.$row["id_exp"].']">'.$job_desc.'</div>'
}
```

At this point I'm stuck, I know I need to generate not only the `div`'s dynamically but also the *toggle* buttons for every `div`.

I really don't know how to:

1. Change my jquery function in order to work with dynamically generated `div`'s
2. How to hide all the `div`'s when document ready.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily do that by using classes (this is untested but should work):

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
  echo '<div id="job_desc'.$row['id_exp'].'" class="hidable">'.$job_desc.'</div>';
}
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.hidable').hide();
   $('.hidable').click(function() {
    var the_id = $(this).attr('id');
   $('#'+the_id).toggle(400);
  });
});
```

**EDIT:**

As I said in my comment, I didn't see the part where you say you want a link tag to toggle the hide/unhide. If it is necessary for your design, you can easily implement the same mechanism and just add a return:false; or event.preventDefault() to avoid the browser following the link; anyway, just give it a class and a (unique) ID, and fetch the latter using the former.

I spent some minuts thinking to a solution but maybe I don't understan what you really want. A single  that hides/unhides all divs?

```
$('.hidable').hide();
$('a#slick-toggle').click(function(){
  $('.hidable').toggle(400);
  return false;
}
```

Or do you want a different link for each div?

**UPDATED:**

Not the most elegant solution, but should work:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
  echo '<div id="job_desc'.$row['id_exp'].'" class="hidable">'.$job_desc.'<a class="slick-toggle" href="desc'.$row['id_exp'].'">toggle</a></div>';
}
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.hidable').hide(); // hides all divs;
    $('a.slick-toggle').click(function(){
      var the_id = $(this).attr('href');  //gets href
      var div_id = $('#job_' + the_id);  //takes the div id, which is made up with the href
      $(div_id).toggle(400);  //now can match the div
      return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Oops, looks like I didn't read the question correctly, jumped the part where you want to use a link tag. With this code you don't need it, but I'll update my answer

Comment: I want a different link for each div. The idea is a list of titles, every title have a description inside a div (the hiddeable divs), every div needs a link to hide it or un hide it.

Comment: syntax err with the `$('#'.div_id).toggle(400);` - concatenate with `+` not `.` - `$('#'+div_id).toggle(400);` -  I do that all the time when switching between js and php

Comment: Thank you @Aaron, as you saw I also do that all the time...Code corrected now! :)

Answer (score 1):

I do the following to show / hide divs ....

I first use the following JS in all pages (ie linked to a single js file)

```
$('.togglelink').live('click',(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#' + $(this).attr('href')).toggle();
    })
);
```

I can break it down as follows :

```
$('.togglelink').live('click',(function(event) {
```

Any element that appears (.live) on my page with the class togglelink - perform the action in the function

```
event.preventDefault();
```

Stop the default - ie the browser following the link

```
$('#' + $(this).attr('href')).toggle();
```

toggle the div with the ID in the href attribute of the anchor......

To make this work I output the following HTML

```
<span class="toggleright"><a class="togglelink" href="showdetails">Show / Hide</a></span>
<span class="subheading">A Heading</span>
<div id="showdetails" style="display:none;">
Some content
</div>
```

I then use CSS to float the show / hide to the right of the page

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason for setting the ID of the div as an array? I would just set the ID to be something like

```
echo '<div id="job_desc_'.$row["id_exp"].'">'.$job_desc.'</div>';
```

The `slick-toggle` link to hide/show the div would need to be updated to call a function with the ID param for the appropriate div...or set with an attribute with the corresponding ID that you can grab when it's clicked to hide the right div.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('div[id^="job_desc_"]').hide();
});
```

That will hide all divs with ids that start with `job_desc_`